# Google Calendar 1.17 API with Service Account - unresolved GoogleClient class

Tags: java, eclipse, api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a simple example case with the 1.17-rc Google Calendar Java API.

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory =JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance()
String email = "test@domain.com";

java.io.File licenseFile = new java.io.File("C:/Dev/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/app/webapps/12334b4c229abc2f7da1c3a9100d5d15c11d9874-privatekey.p12");

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
    .setServiceAccountId("51235964123-k2vr57p9jh0r3i5cj95frvh2qwe35ofg@developer.gserviceaccount.com") 
    .setServiceAccountUser(email)
    .setServiceAccountScopes(new ArrayList<String>(){{add(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);}})
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(licenseFile)
    .build();

    com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar client = 
        new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
        httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("Google Calendar Sync").build();

    Calendar calendar = client.calendars().get(email).execute();
```

I don't get as far as even running this - it's giving me a complaint (in Eclipse) that "The type com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClient$Builder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files".  I have installed the entire Google Calender API dependency ZIP and added all the contained JAR files to my classpath.  But it does really seem like that class isn't in any of them - I see a com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClient in google-api-client-1.17.0-rc.jar, but no com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClient in any of the supplied JARs.

I have Googled around very extensively on this, on two separate occasions, and I can't find anybody else having this problem, so I guess I must be doing something real stupid that I just can't see - if somebody can tell me what, I'd be grateful...

Comment: Nobody seen a similar problem?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you get to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, finally I found out that google-api-client version later then 1.7 has the GoogleClient class.

You can download the jar file here.
http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.api-client/google-api-client/1.7.0-beta/

It'a a late answer, but hopefully this will help someone.